# Recalculation in ExcelVBA and Storing output in each simulation

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to store the the value in C1012 for each simulation from 1 to 1000.
I am recalculating the entire C column of the Worksheet MC.
I have to store the values of Simulation in the column BF 
I have written the code but its not giving any output.

```
Dim i As Integer
```

For i = 1 To 1000

```
SimulationArray(i) = Cells(1012, 3).Value
Worksheet(MC).Column(C).Calculate
```

Next i

Sheets("MC").Range("BF1:BF1000") = SimulationArray

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Multiple issues going on but by having `Cells(1012, 3)`, every array element will hold the same value (because `cells` is constant).

Comment: @findwindow For each simulation the Cell(1012,3) will change and then I have to store 1000 simulated value after recalculation in that cell in the Simulation Array. How to do that ?

Comment: How are you changing that cell? What's the simulation?

Comment: I have all the formuals written in column C , I am using the worksheet function calculate to recalculate the entire C colum 1000 times and then storing C1003 value into SimulationArray for each simulation in the ForLoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub trythis()
Dim SimulationArray(1 To 1000)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 1000

    SimulationArray(i) = Cells(1012, 3).Value
    Sheets("MC").Range("C:C").Calculate
Next i

Sheets("MC").Range("BF1:BF1000").Value = Application.Transpose(SimulationArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this . But why have you written Transpose (Simulation Array)? Is the SimulationArray(i) storing the data along the column dimension?

Comment: The array is horizontal, with out it, the entire column will fill with only the first value.  By transposing, it turns it vertical.

Comment: I have written the code and run ..It says  Compile Error. Only comments may appear after End Sub,End Function or End Property .

Comment: @PankajMani I figured since you did not provide the ends, (Sub and End sub) that this was a small part of a longer sub.  I have added the ends.

Comment: @PankajMani please consider marking as correct, just hit the green check mark under the down arrow.